# simple C++ PUSH notification to GCM such using curl json

Tags: android, c++, json, curl

I try sending mssage from c++ application using Curl and json but I faced this problem CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL i used this code :

```
string  website = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
//Define the header file 
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization:key = ......");
curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");
//  const char* headers[] = { "Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization:key=......" };
string json =     "{ 'registration_ids':['...'],'data': 'none'  } }";

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, website.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
/* Now specify the POST data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str()); 
/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // 
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: I think the problem related to the Lib Curl so sine i work under windows 64 bit  I need to install curl support the ssl( https ) in order to solved this problem :) so is there any document related to install the lib curl with support ssl and https